# How to enable circular scroll in emacs helm

Tags: helm, scrolling, elisp

How do I wrap around and start from the beginning when I have reached the end of items in a helm buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: `(setq helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source t)` should do what you need, the option's documentation is

> helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source is a variable defined in 'helm.el'.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation: Move to end or beginning of source when reaching top or
>   bottom of source. This happen when using 'helm-next/previous-line'.

---

Use <kbd>M-<</kbd>("helm-beginning-of-buffer").

---

<kbd>left</kbd>("helm-previous-source") can always cycle all sources, <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>C-o</kbd> ("helm-next-sources") can cycle all sources when there is no a dummy source.

Comment: This is an alternative. Is there a way that I keep press next and go to the beginning when the end has reached?

Comment: Interesting idea, I didn't find existing command does this, but it is possible to write ourself.

Comment: just customize the `helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source`  option.