# How to disable helm result list to wrap over when scrolling?

Tags: helm

Since recently, when using helm-mini (SPC b b / recent buffers) or helm-swoop (SPC s s / search in buffer) and scrolling with arrow keys (or Ctrl-j) through the results, it doesn't stop at the start/end of the list but jumps from end to start and vice versa.

I find this annoying, because I want to notice when I reached the end of the list / see what is the last entry.

I am using spacemacs in evil mode.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour, so that navigating up/down stops when having reached the start/end of the list? (This is how it behaved before.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source nil)
```

Found the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13470/6695) (the question was for changing it in the opposite direction).